# How to return value from the QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a widget that ends with pressing OK button.  I want that the widget returns a value to the main program (which is in simple example below the obtained value increased by 1).  How can I do this?

Also, is there any more elegant way to show the same QWidget with the different title?

MWE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.End= QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK', self)
        self.End.clicked.connect(self.end)

        MainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        MainLayout.addWidget(self.End)
        self.setLayout(MainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle(str(self.val))
        self.show()

    def end(self):
        # return self.val+1
        self.close()

def main(): 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    for i in range(10):
        ex = MainWindow(i)
        ex.show()
        res = app.exec_()
        print(res)
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you want to open the next window after the previous window closes or should all windows be open?

Comment: @eyllanesc The idea is that the window closes in order to return the data to the main program before opening new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a widget to get some value after some processing, the correct thing is to use `QDialog`, that prevents any other window from opening if you use `exec_()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, val, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.val = val
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        endButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
        endButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(endButton)
        self.setWindowTitle(str(self.val))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.val += 1
        self.accept()

def main(): 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    for i in range(10):
        ex = Dialog(i)
        ex.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        if ex.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print(ex.val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just a question: so all data from closed Dialog are saved.  Forever?  Or are they eventually erased?

Comment: @Pygmalion Explain yourself better I do not understand.

Comment: @Pygmalion Do you want the data processed in the i-th dialog to be used in the (i + 1)-th dialog?

Comment: What I see is that after closing the Dialog you can read all its data.  What happens with these data?  Are they erased after new Dialog is open?  I am just wondering, I don't need those data any more.

Comment: @Pygmalion the data is part of the Dialog, so if the dialog is deleted the data will also be deleted, I have activated the flag `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` that establishes that if the window is closed the window will be deleted from memory. Close does not mean to be removed from memory. As a result: data is deleted from memory when the window is closed.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, having the "@QtCore.pyqtSlot()" decorator before the connected method makes python throw "TypeError: on_clicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'"

Comment: @morph3us I do not understand what are you talking about.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have a very similar set up and copied your solution into my code. It then threw the error mentioned above. Commenting out the decorator from your solution fixed it however. I dont know, probably I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @morph3us I can't comment on some code I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what exactly your intention is with this code. If `val` is supposed to be a counter for the number of `MainWindow` instances, then you must declare it as a static:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    val = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        MainWindow.val += 1
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # ...
        self.setWindowTitle(str(MainWindow.val))
        # ...

def main():
    # ...
    for i in range(10):
        ex = MainWindow()
        # ...
    # ...
```

There is nothing wrong in calling `QWidget::setWindowTitle()` so I don't see a problem here.

If you really want to have it as a non-static class member and each `MainWindow` uses it as some sort of ID, you can easily call the value right after the `ex.show()`:

```
def main(): 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    for i in range(10):
        ex = MainWindow()
        ex.show()
        print(MainWindow.val)
        res = app.exec_()
        print(res)
    sys.exit()
```

Just because you close a widget doesn't mean you have destroyed it so calling the values stored inside the object is not an issue.

However it appears you are not familiar what `QApplication::exec()` is intended for. It runs the main loop of the given application and returns the exit status (you can set it when calling [`exit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit) as the parameter passed to that function). If you simply want to get the value of `val` upon closing a widget you can simply override the `closeEvent` handler and emit a signal. Create a `QObject` instance and connect each `MainWindow` instance's custom close signal to a slot and do with the value whatever you want to.

Comment: the classes that inherit from QObject can not have static variables in python, that is by design, have you tested your solution?

Comment: I know that the example is silly (to make everything less complicated), but I need QWidget to return some data to the main program after closing.  You haven't showed the solution for that one.

Comment: @eyllanesc Tested and it works. I'm rather interested where you read this. I have done it multiple times for classes that directly or indirectly inherit from `QObject` both in PyQt4 and PyQt5.

Comment: @Pygmalion I have described the solution -> read the last part of my answer.